# sqlalchemy ORM with Oracle - ORA-01843:not a valid month error

Tags: python, oracle, sqlalchemy

I am creating a web app in flask using sqlalchemy to query data from a Oracle DB. I my development environment (flask local web server) everything works perfect but when I try to run it in the real web server I got the error ORA-01843 not a valid month error. Initially I thought that it could be something related to the fact that I was running the code inside IIS but later I try to use the flask developement web server inside the server where the IIS is hosted and got exact the same error.I did some search over the internet and found some mentions about setting the NLS_TIMESTAMP_FORMAT ([cx_Oracle 'ORA-01843: not a valid month' with unicode parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15396241/cx-oracle-ora-01843-not-a-valid-month-with-unicode-parameter))
in the session. But I don't how this could be done. The Oracle client is the same in both environments (my laptop and the server) so I think that it may have something to do with the Oracle Client Configuration. Here is the query I am trying to execute.

```
query = db.session.query(intervaldate.TSTART,kpi_db.VALUE)
query = query.filter(intervaldate.ID == kpi_db.INTERVAL_ID)
query = query.filter(intervaldate.TSTART>=t_ini)
query = query.filter(intervaldate.TSTART<=t_end)
query = query.filter(kpi_db.KPI_ID==1)
query = query.filter(kpi_db.CTRL_ID==ctrl_id)
query = query.all()
```

Nothing too much complex. I just inform a time range and two additonal parameters. I my dev environment it works and in the server it does not.
I tried to run this query also in the flask shell and got exactly the same error.
Is there anyone here that ever seen this happening with sqlalchemy?

Answer (score 1):

for anyone that got to this question and is having this problem using pandas, this is my solution, also using the to_date func.

```
     for index, row in df.iterrows():
        row['ROW_IN_DF'] = func.to_date(row['ROW_IN_DF'], 'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS')

        product_line_instance = ProductCatalogLine(**row.to_dict())
        session.add(product_line_instance)
```

Answer (score 0):

Despite of not understanding what is the difference between the two environments I manage to find a solution. sqlAlchemy has a to_date function that properly format the dates for Oracle. So I did this.

```
from sqlalchemy import func

...

query = db.session.query(intervaldate.TSTART,kpi_db.VALUE)
query = query.filter(intervaldate.ID == kpi_db.INTERVAL_ID)
query = query.filter(intervaldate.TSTART>=func.to_date(t_ini,'DD-MM-YYYY'))
query = query.filter(intervaldate.TSTART<=func.to_date(t_end,'DD-MM-YYYY'))
query = query.filter(kpi_db.KPI_ID==1)
query = query.filter(kpi_db.CTRL_ID==ctrl_id)
query = query.all()
```

And it worked perfectly